# How to exclude specific type of an input variable in Python?

Tags: python, string, fibonacci, valueerror

I created a row of Fibonacci numbers. At the beginning is desired input the number to specify the size of Fibonacci series, in fact the size of the row. The number is required to be an integer number >=2.

The outcome is printing out all Fibonacci number until the last number of the row, with their respective indices within the row! After that it's required to take out a slice of the row, and the outcome is to print out all numbers within the slice with their respective indices.

I successfully mastered to exclude all values that do not fall within range specified, but however I had not succeed to exclude numbers and other inputs of undesired types, example would like to exclude float type of an input variable, and string type of an input variable.

I specified that undesirable types of an input variable are float and string! However it reports me an error! How to overcome that, or by another words how to specify the requirement to exclude a floating variable as well as string variable to not report me an error?

The code:

```
while True:
    n = int(input('Please enter the size of Fibonacci row - positive integer number(N>=2)!'))

    if n < 2:
        print('This is not valid number! Please enter valid number as specified above!')
        continue
    elif type(n)==float: # this line is not working!
        print('The number has to be an integer type, not float!')
        continue
    elif type(n)==str: # this line is not working!
        print(  'The number has to be an integer type, not string!')
        continue
    else:
        break

def __init__(self, first, last):
    self.first = first
    self.last = last

def __iter__(self):
    return self

def fibonacci_numbers(n):
    fibonacci_series =  [0,1]
    for i in range(2,n):
        next_element = fibonacci_series[i-1] + fibonacci_series[i-2]
        fibonacci_series.append(next_element)
    return fibonacci_series

while True:
    S = int(input('Enter starting number of your slice within Fibonacci row (N>=2):'))

    if S>n:
        print(f'Starting number can not be greater than {n}!')
        continue
    elif S<2:
        print('Starting number can not be less than 2!')
        continue
    elif type(S)==float: # this line is not working!
        print('The number can not be float type! It has to be an integer!')
        continue
    elif type(S)==str: # this line is not working!
        print('Starting number can not be string! It has to be positive integer number greater than or equal to 2!')
        continue
    else:
        break

while True:
    E = int(input(f'Enter ending number of your slice within Fibonacci row(E>=2) and (E>={S}):'))

    if E<S:
        print('Ending number can not be less than starting number!')
        continue
    elif E>n:
        print(f'Ending number can not be greater than {n}')
        continue
    elif E<2:
        print('Ending number can not be greater than 2!')
        continue
    elif type(E)==float: # this line is not working!
        print('Ending number can not be float type! It has to be an integer type!')
        continue
    elif type(E) ==str: # this line is not working!
        print(f'Ending number can not be string! It has to be positive integer number greater than or equal to {S}')
        continue
    else:
        break

print('Fibonacci numbers by index are following:')
for i, item in enumerate(fibonacci_numbers(n),start = 0):
    print(i, item)

fibonacci_numbers1 = list(fibonacci_numbers(n))
print('Fibonacci numbers that are within your slice with their respective indices are following:')
for i, item in enumerate(fibonacci_numbers1[S:E], start = S):
    print(i, item)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved :-) simply add **try except** block in ur code like the following:

```
while True:
  try:
    num = int(input("Enter an integer number: "))
    break
  except ValueError:
      print("Invalid input. Please input integer only")  
      continue

print("num:", num)
```

upvote & check :-)

Comment: Perfectly useful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

at the first line

```
    n = int(input('Please enter the size of Fibonacci row - positive integer number(N>=2)!'))
```

you're converting the input to int, so whatever the user provides it will be converted to an int.

if you want your code to be working, replace it with this

```
n = input('Please enter the size of Fibonacci row - positive integer number(N>=2)!')
```

Comment: I'm not sure if just that will be enough because then `n` will always return a string. The right thing here is to have fallbacks e.g. always first try coercing to a float - and if that works without an error, then try converting to an int.

Then, if the coerced float and the coerced int aren't equal, an error can be raised or a message can or displayed about float to int coercion.

If the coerced int and coerced float are equal, then the value entered is probably actually an integer and the execution works as expected.

Note that the order of comparison also needs to chance.

Comment: A part of problem I resolved to exclude float type of data! However still struggling how to exclude string type of data!

Answer (score 0):

Use an `try/except/else` to test the input.  `int()` raises a `ValueError` if a string value isn't strictly an integer.

```
>>> while True:
...   s = input('Enter an integer: ')
...   try:
...     n = int(s)
...   except ValueError:
...     print('invalid')
...   else:
...     break
...
Enter an integer: 12a
invalid
Enter an integer: 1.
invalid
Enter an integer: 1.5
invalid
Enter an integer: 1+2j
invalid
Enter an integer: 5
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check type, `isinstance` is usually better, e. g.:

```
if isinstance(var, int) or isinstance(var, str):
    pass  # do something here
```