# Allowing my Python program to accept non-integer values

Tags: python

I am having trouble finding a way to allow my Python project to accept a non-integer value and not crash. My intention is that when the user inputs a non-integer value or any value other than the ones assigned by the random sampkle, the game will prompt the function "repeatr()" which will tell them to input the value again.

I've put in the entire solution, but the most relevant sections are in bold and it's that particular section that I want to allow to prompt the repeatr() function instead of crashing

```
import random

user_wins = 0
user_draws = 0
user_losses = 0
rounds = 0

def closr():
    quit()

def repeatr():
    print("That is not a valid input. Please input a correct value.")

**def promptr():
    print("Please select an input from the following options.")**

options = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

randomlist = random.sample(range(1, 5), 3)

randomr = randomlist

x=1
while x == 1:
    user_input = int(input("Type 5/4/3/2/1 or Q to quit."))
    if user_input in options:
        x=2
    elif user_input != options:
        repeatr()
        continue
    elif user_input == "q":
        closr()

**y=1
while rounds < 10:
    promptr()
    player_choice = int(input(randomlist))
    npc = random.randint(1,5)
    if player_choice in randomr:
        print("Your opponent has drawn: ", npc)
        y=2
    else:
        repeatr()
        continue**
        
    if npc > int(player_choice):
        print("You have been defeated this round.")
        user_losses = user_losses + 1
        print("The score is:" , user_wins , ":" , user_losses)
        rounds = rounds + 1
    elif npc < player_choice:
        print ("You have won this round.")
        user_wins = user_wins + 1
        print ("The score is:" , user_wins , ":" , user_losses)
        rounds = rounds + 1
    elif npc == player_choice:
        print ("You have drawn this round.")
        user_draws = user_draws + 1
        print ("The score is:" , user_wins , ":" , user_losses)
        rounds = rounds + 1

rounds = 10
if user_losses < user_wins:
        print("You have won the game!")
elif user_losses > user_wins:
        print("You have lost this game. Better luck next time!")
elif user_losses == user_wins:
        print("The game has ended in a draw.")

print("the number of wins you had was:" , user_wins)
print("the number of draws you had was:" , user_draws)
print("the number of losses you had was:" , user_losses)
print("The final score was (Player vs CPU):" , user_wins, ":" , user_losses)

u=1
while u == 1:
    resu=input("Press Q to quit the game.")
    if resu=="q":
        closr()
```

I hope the question makes sense.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63647104/235698) for a `try/except` solution

Comment: something you should consider is that you can never trust the user's input. you are converting the user's input to an integer every time. If the user enters anything other than an integer, your program will crash. I recommend using an IDE as well, it will give you a lot of hints (it will tell you that a certain part of your code is currently unreachable)

Comment: FYI: styling of text (bolding, italics,...) does not work within code blocks. If you wanted to "highlight" specific lines of code, it would probably be best to embed a separate second code block with just those lines (while keeping the original, full code intact).

Comment: For the future, consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.